# How to play video from youku using javascript?

Tags: javascript, video, youku

How to play video from youku using javascript ?

I tried to do like this but not work, how can i do that ?

```
<iframe id="test" src="https://player.youku.com/embed/XMjUzMzY2ODQ4OA==" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 50%; height: 50%;"></iframe>


<div style=" position: fixed; top: 56%; " onclick="play_fn()">Play</div>

<script>
function play_fn(){
    var test = document.getElementById('test');
    test.play();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Does youku have API documentation you could look at?

Comment: Maybe you should look at the API youku have to offer? https://cloud.youku.com/docs?id=0

Answer (score 1):

`play()` is a method found on `<video>` and `<audio>` elements. An `<iframe>` is just a means to embed a URL in a page. It provides no API for playing media.

Unless youku provide an API that you can access (I couldn't find one with a quick search), then there is no way to trigger playback from your page.

Standard cross origin security restrictions imposed by browsers prevent you manipulating the embedded page with JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

Check my solution. You can figure out the styles for your own case, I'm using the `span` as overlay above the video and when you click on it, it disappears and the video plays.

```js
const videoSection = document.querySelector('.video');
    if(videoSection) {
     const playBtn = document.querySelector('.play-btn');
     playBtn.addEventListener('click', playVideo);
    }

    function playVideo() {
     const iframeHolder = document.querySelector('.iframe-holder');
     const iframeEl = document.querySelector('.iframe-holder iframe');
     const playStr = '?autoplay=true';
     let baseUrl = iframeEl.getAttribute('src');
     
     iframeHolder.classList.add('play');
     iframeEl.setAttribute('src', `${baseUrl}${playStr}`);
     iframeEl.setAttribute('allow', 'autoplay');
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">

    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="video">
<span class='play-btn'></span>
    <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"   src="https://player.youku.com/embed/XMjUzMzY2ODQ4OA=="></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
    const videoSection = document.querySelector('.video');
    if(videoSection) {
     const playBtn = document.querySelector('.play-btn');
     playBtn.addEventListener('click', playVideo);
    }

    function playVideo() {
     const iframeHolder = document.querySelector('.iframe-holder');
     const iframeEl = document.querySelector('.iframe-holder iframe');
     const playStr = '?autoplay=true';
     let baseUrl = iframeEl.getAttribute('src');
     
     iframeHolder.classList.add('play');
     iframeEl.setAttribute('src', `${baseUrl}${playStr}`);
     iframeEl.setAttribute('allow', 'autoplay');
    }
    <!doctype html>
    <html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">

    <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="video">
    <span class='play-btn'></span>
    <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"   src="https://player.youku.com/embed/XMjUzMzY2ODQ4OA=="></iframe>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Refer this code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/dummy.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">




  <style type="text/css">
      #overlay {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 100px; 
  color: #FFF; 
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.3);
  width: 640px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  z-index: 2147483647;
}

#v {
  z-index: 1;
}
  </style>

  <title>Overlay HTML over video player</title>






<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function() {
  var video = document.getElementById('v');
  video.play();
}//]]> 

</script>


</head>

<body>
    <video id="v" controls="">
    <source id="webm" src="https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/devstories.webm" type="video/webm">

    <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Video element.</p>


  </video>
  <div id="overlay" style='display: none;'>This is HTML overlay on top of the video! </div>






</body>
</html>
```